# Linq: Getting a List<String> from List<Customer> based on customer.name

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Customer>` and need to get a `List<string>` based on the Customer.Name field. This is for a picker UI.

How can I query a List for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<string> names = custs.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick test (which may be faulty) tells me this is a bit faster:

```
var customerNames = myCustomers.ConvertAll(c => c.Name);
```

At least it's another way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var customerNames = myCustomers.Select( c=> c.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another syntax...

```
var customerNames = (from c in myCustomers select c.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Also, if you're only going to be reading the names and not manipulating them, you can get away with dropping the .ToList() part and iterating IEnumerable<string>.